# C++ Order of Evaluation of Subexpressions with Logical Operators

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

There are lots of questions on concepts of **precedence** and **order of evaluation** but I failed to find one that refers to my special case.

Consider the following statement:

```
if(f(0) && g(0)) {};
```

Is it **guaranteed** that f(0) will be evaluated first? Notice that the operator is &&.

My confusion stems from what I've read in "The C++ Programming Language, (Stroustrup, 4ed, 2013)".

In section 10.3.2 of the book, it says:

> The order of evaluation of **subexpressions** within an expression is **undefined**. In particular, you cannot assume that the expression is evaluated left-to-right. For example:
>
> int x = f(2)+g(3);       // undefined whether f() or g() is called first

This seems to apply to all operators **including** && operator, but in a following paragraph it says:

> The operators , (comma), && (logical and), and || (logical or) **guarantee** that their left-hand operand is evaluated before their right-hand operand.

There is also another mention of this in section 11.1.1:

> The && and || operators evaluate their second argument only if necessary, so they can be used to control evaluation order (§10.3.2). For example:
>
> while (p && !whitespace(p)) ++p;
>
> Here, p is not dereferenced if it is the nullptr.

This last quote implies that && and || evaluate their 1st argument first, so it seems to reinforce my assumption that operators mentioned in 2nd quote are exceptions to 1st quote, but I cannot draw a definitive conclusion from this last example either, as the expression contains only **one** subexpression as opposed to my example, which contains **two**.

Comment: In a nutshell, logical operators are special cased.

Comment: I cannot find a question in your post.  If your question was whether `f` or `g` is evaluated first, you answered it yourself.

Comment: No one would believe me, I have encountered a case - if(expr1 && expr2), expr2 ran first. But I haven't encountered another case after that. Thus, I guess there was something wrong within expr1 and it was optimized, so it didn't run at first. But I can't find the code to proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The special sequencing behavior of `&&`, `||`, and `,` is well-established in C and C++.  The first sentence you quoted should say "The order of evaluation of subexpressions within an expression is generally unspecified" or "With a few specific exceptions, the order of evaluation of subexpressions within an expression is unspecified".

You asked about C++, but [this question](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpointops.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpointops.html) is pertinent.

---

Addendum: I just realized that "unspecified" is a better word in these rules than "undefined".  Writing something like `f() + g()` doesn't give you undefined behavior.  You just have no way of knowing whether `f` or `g` might be called first.

Comment: Vague accepted answer. I think the answer could be much more simpler like: "Yes, for && and || and , it is guaranteed." The links are not working as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is guaranteed that `f(0)` will be completely evaluated first.

This is to support behaviour known as *short-circuiting*, by which we don't need to call the second function at all if the first returns `false`.